# Perl: Encontrar uma linha em um txt combinando palavras digitadas?

Tags: regex, perl

Boa tarde,

Tenho um bloco de notas com várias linhas digitadas como por exemplo:

```
★ Bayonet
★ Bayonet | Autotronic (Battle-Scarred)
★ Bayonet | Blue Steel (Minimal Wear)
★ Bayonet | Case Hardened (Battle-Scarred)
★ Bayonet | Case Hardened (Factory New)
★ Bayonet | Case Hardened (Field-Tested)
```

No meu código uma das linhas vai esperar a entrada no teclado perguntando qual nome deseja encontrar

```
use strict;
open(FILEHANDLE,'<','filtradas.txt') or die "Arquivo não pode ser aberto\n";
my @linhas = <FILEHANDLE>;
close(FILEHANDLE);
print "Informe o nome do item que deseja encontrar: ";
my $nome = <STDIN>; chomp($nome);
foreach my $linhas(@linhas) {
chomp($linhas);
if($linhas =~ m/$nome/gi) {
    print $linhas."\n";
}
}
```

A pergunta é : Existe alguma forma de criar um regex que se por exemplo eu digitar na entrada do teclado "Bayonet Case" ele me print todos os resultados do bloco de notas que contenha o Bayonet + Case na mesma linha? No caso:

```
★ Bayonet | Case Hardened (Battle-Scarred)
★ Bayonet | Case Hardened (Factory New)
★ Bayonet | Case Hardened (Field-Tested)
```

Me desculpem se não consegui ser claro, caso não tenham entendido eu tento explicar de outra forma.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido com a seguinte função :

```
$nome =~ s/\s+/.*/g;
```

o que transforma "bayonet case" em ( "bayonet.*case". ).

Obrigado Hernan.